# Is it possible to utilize dynamic targets with autotools?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to make a cross compiler that will generate different file names for different targets. This is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include

AM_LDFLAGS = -L$(abs_top_builddir)/win -Wl,--whole-archive -lnvml -Wl,--no-whole-archive

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libjnvml-$(target_triplet).la 
libjnvml_$(target_triplet)_la_SOURCES = jnvml.c
libjnvml_$(target_triplet)_la_LIBADD = ../swig/libjnvml_wrap.la
```

I expected this to resolve to libjnvml-i686-pc-mingw32.la but instead the build failed because it couldn't find the literal filename libjnvml-$(target_triplet).la

Comment: perhaps using `@TARGET_TRIPLET@` in Makefile.am and doing `AC_SUBST(TARGET_TRIPLET, $(target_triplet))` in configure.ac will do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

autoconf.ac:

```
AC_INIT([dynamic-target], 1.0)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_SUBST(TARGET_TRIPLET, 'foo-triplet')
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main-@TARGET_TRIPLET@
main_@TARGET_TRIPLET@_SOURCES = main.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer pushed me in the right direction, the only difference is that I ended up needing to use AC_SUBST(TARGET_TRIPLET, "$target") in in configure.ac to make it automatic.

Comment: I'm using AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM in my configure.ac which I believe is where the $target comes from originally.